# Multicast at high speed over Wifi/AP? higher speed?

Tags: wifi, multicast, openwrt

I have a small dedicated wifi network setup specifically to carry a multicast multimedia package.. no other use (no web or other data on this network, due to the arrangement).

The issue I've found is that clients are not receiving a true multicast transmission - they're actually receiving unicast from the AP.

Some APs have options to "convert Multicast to Unicast", as supposedly it raises the QoS of the packet to a faster delivery.when I turn this off, the packet delay is FAR higher for any device/all devices - it's far worse...

However, as I need to deliver the multicast to more clients (dozens), i need it to truly multicast (ie., 1 RF transmission transmitting the entire packet to dozens of clients).

My clients are listening for the multicast port, but i need the AP to actually multicast/broadcast the packet..

How can this be accomplished? I've looked at various 'open source' options (OpenWRT etc), but am unsure how to actually configure APs to accomplish this.

I know that in general, the wifi protocol runs multicast at the LOWESt possible speed. Is this something which can be adjusted in say OpenWRT?

Please note: i am very familiar with the potential fallout - some clients not getting all packets, signal issues, etc.  This application has other factors which necessitate a true multicast process at a higher speed.

HOW can I force multicast to run at a higher speed? If I simply disable low speeds/PHY (Ie., turn off 2.4ghz, set 5ghz at only 80mhz and mcs9), will this force multicast to run faster/higher?  How can I speed it up?

I'm trying Engenius APs running on OpenWRT.  But I'm open to running ANY AP which will handle this or which allows me better management of the multicast options.

Comment: The _highest_ speed you can possibly get with true multicast is the _lowest_ speed of any connected client. The obvious thing to do, then, is to use more APs and thereby ensure that clients are never far enough away to have low data rates.

Comment: is it possible to force APs to ONLY run at xxx rate instead of a lower rate?  is the "data rates" described the MCS0 or MCS1 (0-9) listed in APs?  I'm running 802.11ac only, setting it to 80mhz only, and datarate is set to Auto...